# How to prove that $\operatorname{homeo}(f)=\operatorname{Im}f$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$ is a homeomorphism, prove that $\operatorname{homeo}(f) = \operatorname{Im} f$, where $\operatorname{Im}f$ is the image of the function $f$, I tried proving these using equivalence  of sets, by assuming that $\operatorname{homeo}(f)\subseteq\operatorname{Im}f$ and vice versa, but it doesn't really seem to make sense. Pls is there any way I can prove the equivalence?

Comment: What is $homeo(f)$?

Comment: Equivalence and equality of sets are Not one and the same thing.

Comment: Homeo(f) is the topological  homeomorphism, so this means that $f$ satisfies all conditions of Homeomorphism, so how do I Proof that the homeomorphism of the function $f$ is equal to the image of the function?

Comment: image is a set. You can talk about equality if $\mbox{homeo}(f)$ is also a set. If you say it's a topological homeomorphism, then you say it is a subset of $X\times Y$. It makes no sense to talk about its equality to the image of $f$ which is contained in $Y$.